# Generating URL from route in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm a ZF2 beginner and working on my first website.
I need a multilanguage site and have some troubles with routing.
I configured my routes like this:

```
'lang' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/:lang',
        'constraints' => array(
            'lang' => 'en|it'
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/home',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index'
                )
            )
        ),
        'other routes' ...
    )
)
```

So, I can later use `/lang` to set up the translator. (`www.site.com/it/home` or `www.site.com/en/home`)

Now I need to add links in the layout to switch languages, so I need to generate an URL to the same page displayed, but switching "it" with "en" and vice-versa. How can I do that? Can I somehow obtain just the following part of the route (`'/home'`, `'/about'`, `'/show/gallery'`, etc.) from the view?

Comment: I am sure you can! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I get the "lang" value with
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang')
but don't know how to get the route value from the literal route...

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters in the route options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply can do the following in your layout/view:

```
//using url view helper
echo $this->url(null, array('lang' => 'en'));
```

By given null as routename the helper will take the current matched routename, so theoretically it should work.
But unfortunately i can't say what happens if the route is segment with already set params, sry.

Comment: Wow, that worked great, and very easy, thanks a lot!
The only thing is when I'm on the root page (www.site.com), the generated link won't add the /en, but every other page works!

Comment: I figured out how to fix the root page issue, but a problem I have now is that, when I go to a non existing route, the url view helper generates the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No RouteMatch instance provided'
and the 404 error page doesn't show up.
Any idea how can I avoid that? Thanks.